# negative precision values in ostream

Tags: c++, floating-point, stream, precision

This is more of a question of curiosity but does anyone know how negative precision values are handled in C++?  For example:

```
double pi = 3.14159265;

cout.precision(-10);
cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);

cout << pi << endl;
```

I've tried this out and using GCC and it seems that the precision value is ignored but I was curious if there is some official line on what happens in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely (and wrongly, IMHO) the C++ Standard specifies  a signed type (streamsize) as the parameter for precision, so it won't be converted to a large number. However, the standard is silent on what a negative number might mean, if anything.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any specification of this behaviour neither in [C++03](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B03#Language_standard) nor in draft of [C++0x (N3092)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x). However, the [C89](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89) standard says

> **7.19.6.1 The fprintf function**
>
> A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted.

I would expect that C++ std::ostream behaviour is consistent with the C I/O printf. fprintf and related functions.

A quick test with Visual C++ 10.0 and GCC 4.4.1 suggests it to be this way and negative precision means precision omitted. And, precision omitted means a default value which is **6** places as specified in  **27.5.4.1 basic_ios constructors** in **Table 125**